# Cannot scroll up in Docker Container bash session

Tags: docker

I am using an ubuntu docker image with a MacOS host. I am accessing the shell via the following command:

```
docker run -it myubuntu
```

I have tried with both `bash` and `zsh` inside the container, I am unable to scroll up in the terminal session, the content is just blank. This is demonstrated in the screenshot where I attempt to scroll up:

[image: no scroll]

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before and if so, is there a known fix?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you provide a minimum reproducible example? I can run `docker run -it ubuntu` in my macOS and scroll up without any issues at all.

Comment: `Preferences > Profiles > Terminal` and select `unlimited scrollback buffer`